# How to kill a component state on a mouse event React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a popup that turns on/off when I hover over/leave a button, currently it's set to false in my props, I would like to set it to true so when the load pages you see the pop up but when the use hovers over it, the state resets back to false so I can hover over it again and see it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```js
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.state = { isHovered: false };
   this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this);
 
 }

 handleHover(){
    this.setState({
        isHovered: !this.state.isHovered
    });
 }

 render() {

    const box = this.state.isHovered ? "box open" : "box";

    return(

       <a className="spot1" 
          onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} 
          onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}>
      </a>

      <div className={box}>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor si</p>
      </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a second variable to check if your component was loaded/rendered for first time,
Below you can find a simple example.

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {loaded : true, hovered : false};

  }

  popState () {
    const {loaded, hovered} = this.state; 
    // check if the component was loaded
    // which will be only once
    // because the state for loaded will be set to false
    if (loaded) {
        return this.setState({
          hovered : !hovered,
          loaded : false
        });
    }
    this.setState({
      hovered : !hovered
    });
  }

  render () {
    const {loaded, hovered} = this.state;
    let box;
    // first page reload
    if (loaded) {
      box = 'show';
    } else {
      box = hovered ? 'show' : 'hide';
    }

    return (
      <a 
        onMouseEnter={this.popState.bind(this)} 
        onMouseLeave={this.popState.bind(this)}>
        My link
        <div 
          className={box}>Tooltip</div>
      </a>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: just tried it but just got me back to add and removing class when i hover over it but not loading true when it first loads

Comment: I believe you are making a mistake or something because it works, please take a look https://jsbin.com/pazesovose/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You have the making of what you want, it's not hooked up correctly yet.

First, set your `isHovered: true` so that the popup appears on page load.

Next, change the function `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to `this.handleHover`, that's all you should need to do.

Comment: i've already set it to true but when i hover over and out of it, pop up remains up until i hover over it, the opposite of what i want after i hover over it.